# Sumo simulation terminology

Tags: sumo

When I run sumo simulation via command line, there's a line that reads `vehicle TOT 12500 ACT 323` what does that mean?

I guess it has something to deal with current vehicles that is on the road.

I am simulating a large network and using `randomTrip.py` to generate trips and then using `DUAROUTER` to generate routes. I would like to take a look into the vehicles on the road to monitor whether are the routes generated feasible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TOT refers to the total number of vehicles which have been simulated in the current simulation run (including the vehicles which already arrived), ACT denotes the number vehicles currently in the network.

For having a look at the vehicles simply start sumo with gui (using the sumo-gui executable)